# Twisted process execution issues

Tags: python, twisted, process

I am having some problems with Twisted and running a series of processes that execute scripts one after another and returning the exit code.

To test this I have create five test scripts (test1.py, test2.py etc) each of which just have the following in them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a = 1
b = 2
total = a + b
```

(the only difference in the files are the numbers that `a` and `b` are set to (to give the scripts some variation)).

I then have the following script that should run the five test scripts one by one and then print their exit codes:

```
from twisted.internet import glib2reactor
glib2reactor.install()
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

import os.path

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ProcessProtocol

from ubuntuone.platform.tools import SyncDaemonTool

scriptslocation = "/home/jono/Desktop"

class SubprocessReturnCodeProtocol(ProcessProtocol):      
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.returnCodeDeferred = defer.Deferred()

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        self.returnCodeDeferred.callback(reason.value.exitCode)

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print data

class ScriptChecker():
    def __init__(self):
        print "init"
        self.run_scripts()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def run_scripts(self):
        print "run scripts"

        accoms = [  { "script" : os.path.join(scriptslocation, "test1.py") },
                    { "script" : os.path.join(scriptslocation, "test2.py") },
                    { "script" : os.path.join(scriptslocation, "test3.py") },
                    { "script" : os.path.join(scriptslocation, "test4.py") },
                    { "script" : os.path.join(scriptslocation, "test5.py") }]

        for accom in accoms:
            print "Running: " + str(accom["script"])
            exitcode = yield self.run_a_subprocess([accom["script"]])
            print "Exit code: " + str(exitcode)

    def run_a_subprocess(self, command):
        pprotocol = SubprocessReturnCodeProtocol()
        reactor.spawnProcess(pprotocol, command[0], command, env=os.environ)        
        return pprotocol.returnCodeDeferred

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ScriptChecker()
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    reactor.run()
```

Unfortunately I am seeing some pretty erratic behavior. Most times the scripts don't all run and it gets stuck on one of them and does not continue, and then every so often it runs all scripts as expected.

I am fairly new to Twisted and not sure what is going on; any ideas?

Comment: The code seems basically sound.  I can't reproduce the problems you're describing, either: the five programs reliably run each time (for at least ten attempts in a row).  Perhaps the specific version of gtk2 or one of the other related libraries is implicated in the misbehavior (ie, perhaps it is a bug in a specific version of one of those, or in an interaction between specific versions of more than one of these).

Comment: I'm also having difficulty reproducing the problem. 

I've made a best effort attempt to get something that runs locally, which you can see at lp:~jml/+junk/bacon.  I've run it quite a few times now (on my precise machine) and I can't see any failure.  Perhaps it would help if you could produce something minimal and runnable and share the output that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You're importing the `DBus` thing after you've installed the reactor; I suspect that this is causing some undesirable interactions within GTK itself, which might cause signals to be lost or handled by the wrong code.

If you change the top of your file to

```
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
from twisted.internet import glib2reactor
glib2reactor.install()
```

does that fix anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Same issue. Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Upon speaking to Glyph in #twisted, he suspects this may be a bug in the Ubuntu Twisted package as the code here should work. I will file a bug and point towards this question.

Comment: Hi all, just to let you know, I filed a bug about this in Launchpad at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/twisted/+bug/949685 - thanks!